# Edit build.gradle through bitrise workflow

Tags: shell, build.gradle, react-native, build-tools, bitrise

I have to normalize the build tool versions of the imported dependencies in react-native android part before run the project.

The solution that I came up with is adding following snippet to the root build.gradle,

```
subprojects {
    ...
    afterEvaluate { subproject ->
        if ((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || 
            subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Rather than adding this manually, I need to edit this build.gradle and add the snippet through a script or shell command. This has to be done using bitrise.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out myself.
Can use file overwrite mechanism, for example in my case used 'Change value in file' step to overwrite the build.gradle easily.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]